# Wo compounds in Relativsatz - *worin* or *in dem*

Tags: relative-clause

Why are  "Das Zimmer, worin ich stehe, ist leer." and "Das Zimmer, in dem ich stehe, ist leer" both correct

But "Der Stil, worin man schreibt, ist wichtig" is wrong with the correct form being "in dem" rather than "worin"?

Comment: just a side note: Zimmer is neuter, not masculine, hence it is *das Zimmer*. I have made an edit

Comment: Great question, and a great inconsistency that native speakers don't even notice! It seems as if the correspondence "in" --> "wo" is acceptable for the direct use, but less so for the figurative use, but even I couldn't really say *why*.

Comment: @KilianFoth Does worin (or any other wo-compound) not have the more general meaning of 'in which' rather than just 'in where'?

Comment: @ZhanfengLim It does have that meaning, but preferably for actual location, such as "The cat is *in* the box." - not so much for figurative meaning, such as "The novel is *in* an ancient style."

Answer (score 1):

You write correctly that style matters :-) Hence, `worin` refers mostly or exclusively to a location. You ask `where` or `wherein`, while `in dem` is much more general. You ask `In what style, in what room.` Therefore `in dem` fits for both and `worin` only for room.

Answer (score 1):

The adverb *wo* relates to a *location* - which is perfectly valid for a room.

But even if you write **in** a specific style, this is no location, so "wo" cannot refer to it.

(I wouldn't say it's necessarily wrong from a language POV, but rather from a logical one. Dictionaries consider such a usage colloquial - A lot of German native speakers will accept this as a perfect sentence)

Comment: But I was taught that the wo- in wo compounds do not mean where, but a more general which.

"Ich weiß nicht, wofür das ist." is valid, although no 'where' is involved too isn't it?

Comment: This depends. In *wohin* it introduces a location or more exactly a direction, in *wohingegen* or even *wo hingegen* it's not!

Comment: ^the word in question was worin however @Janka

Comment: *worin* still asks for a location.

Comment: Yes, but for *worin* there's no such counterexample. As often, there is no simple rule you could rely on.